# How to over-ride "Menu" button at left with back button after ajax request in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have added one menu button at the top left corner, which comes just when you open the website. And all the links in the page call external pages through ajax request ( as given default in JQM ).
Now previously when i had menu button at right i used to get a back button at left after any ajax request, but since the time i have shifted the menu button to the right, back button comes no more. 
Can someone please tell me how to override the menu button after ajax requests?

Comment: Can you provide some code or jsfiddle for your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `<a>` tag with  `data-rel="back"` to your header. JQM will style & function it as a back button.